# How to repeat similar provider in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have to create a server in 30 AWS providers.

i tried copy providers with "count", "alias" and variable block "type=list(string)", but got this message:

```
The provider argument name "count" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.
```

but it is too hard to type and manage 30 providers in a `main.tf`.

Here is my `main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws={
        source = "Hashicorp/aws"
        version="~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  count = 6
  region = var.region
  alias = "man01_${count.index}"
  access_key = var.list_ak["${count.index}"]
  secret_key = var.list_sk["${count.index}"]
}

data "aws_instance" "man01_instance" {
  count = 6
  provider = "aws.man01_${count.index}"
  ...
}
```

I don't have any idea about this...

Answer (score 1):

This is (as of Aug 2022) not possible with pure Terraform. The ability for providers using `for_each` or `count` is a long standing request in the Terraform GitHub project ([link](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24476)).

Comment: Damn. Thank you for answer, Carlo.